# Delete Contacts but keep Prospects in Pardot

Tags: pardot

I have a client with a few hundred Contacts in SFDC that we want to delete.  These Contacts are linked to Prospects in Pardot (via CRM Contact ID).  When the Contacts get deleted, the synchronization from Salesforce to Pardot will cause these Prospects to be deleted.

But, we want to keep the Prospects in Pardot along with all of their activities.

What's the best way to keep them from being deleted?